# Updating fields only if file was modified

Tags: java, file, timestamp

I have a JSON file containing some configuration data. Parsing it works all well, but I am trying to achieve a live update of the configuration. Thus, I set a scheduler to do the task every few seconds, and it works all well either. However, if no modification was made to the configuration since the latest parsing, I want to avoid the overhead of parsing the file once again.

I have written the following code to achieve that, however the field variable `timestamp` remains at zero despite `this.timestamp = latestTimestamp;` is executed while `latestTimestamp` holds the latest timestamp. I am confused now as it makes absolutely no sense to me. What am I missing here?

```java
@NonNull private String configFilePath;
@Getter private JSONObject configuration;
private long timestamp = 0;

  /**
   * update the fields
   * @throws IOException if an error occurred while opening / reading the file
   * @throws ParseException if an error occurred parsing the JSON file
   */
  public void update() throws IOException, ParseException {
    long latestTimestamp = getLatestTimestamp(this.configFilePath);
    if (this.timestamp == latestTimestamp)
      return;

    this.configuration = this.parse(this.configFilePath);
    this.timestamp = latestTimestamp;
    // the above condition results in `false` when called again despite file is not modified
    // because this.timestamp somehow remains 0
  }
```

The above code is a simplified version. The complete Class can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/PnaYEBJa).

Comment: So I think "the field variable timestamp remains at zero" is only possible if your scheduler is creating a new object of your class JSONUpdater, which resets the timestamp variable to 0 again. Try making it Singleton. Also why is there no Service, Bean or any type of Component annotation on your class?

Comment: I had started with going for an MD5 digest to compare at first. When it didn't work, started parting into multiple seperate classes going almost Calesthenics-like. But thanks, that makes sense and means: I have alot to refactor first before going any further.

Comment: So is that the root cause of your problem or you are still figuring out.

Comment: Sorry for my late response. Yes, that was the problem indeed. Sometimes, some problems are just too simple to even think it could be the case haha

Comment: Happy to help. I shall add it as an Answer so that others can find this solution easily. Do accept and upvote the answer, for better good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think **"the field variable timestamp remains at zero"** is only possible if your scheduler is creating a new object of your class `JSONUpdater`, which resets the `timestamp` variable to 0 again. Try making it `Singleton`.